# Is there a parameter for MSDOS commands (e.g. ipconfig) that cause them to wait for input before disappearing?

Tags: command-line, cmd

When I run e.g. `ipconfig` using the Run command (windows key+R), once the program has executed it immediately closes the instance of the command line interface, is there any universal parameter I can add to:

- `ipconfig`
- `nslookup`
- `dir`
- etc...

to ensure that the results stay printed in the console window?

Comment: Unless you're using Win 3.1, it's not MSDOS in any way/shape/form.

Comment: nslookup is interactive anyway if you start it without parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `cmd` with the `/k` switch:

```
cmd /k ipconfig
```

Comment: In case your curious from the help doc of cmd ... the /k parameter is the opposite of the /c parameter

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Answer (score 9):

There is also the ability to concatenate commands

& is used to just post multible commands in a line
&& will break if the last command wasn't successful

```
cmd /k ipconfig & pause & exit
```

Comment: Even better, because it immediateley exits after a key stroke.

Answer (score 3):

Or you just execute "cmd" via the Run command, which will open a DOS prompt.
If you type "ipconfig" there, the command prompt remains open.

(ok, I admit: basically it's the same like "cmd /k ipconfig")